# How to decide we have to choose frame work or dynamic library

Tags: cocoa

can you just tell me for which type of requirement we should choose framework or dynamic library? I mean when should I decide to use frame work rather than using dynamic library or vice versa?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have any answers worthy of acceptance, that is. Don't just accept answers to drive the number up. http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2010-03-13/the-green-checkmark-of-acceptance

Comment: Thanks peter for sending that link. I am new to this forum and i have no much idea about this site.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A framework can include resources such as images, sounds, and plist files. A dylib file can't, or at least not easily and not cleanly.

If you're targeting the Mac, make a framework—there's virtually no reason not to. If you're targeting the iPhone, make a static library (which also cannot easily include resources, but frameworks aren't available on the iPhone). If you're targeting anything else (e.g., Linux), you should probably offer both static-library and shared-library targets and let people choose for themselves.